# SQL: Include zeroes in count within a table

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a table like this:

```
+---------+---------+
|   id1   |   id2   |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       2 |
|       2 |       2 |
|       3 |       1 |
|       4 |       1 |
|       5 |       3 |
|       6 |       2 |
+---------+---------+
```

I would like to, for each id2, count how many id1's it is associated with, including zero values. Currently I have this:

```
select id2, count(*) cnt 
from mytable group by id2
```

Which works partially, except it produces this output:

```
+---------+---------+
|   id2   |   cnt   |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       2 |
|       2 |       3 |
|       3 |       1 |
+---------+---------+
```

I am trying to get an output like this:

```
+---------+---------+
|   id2   |   cnt   |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       2 |
|       2 |       3 |
|       3 |       1 |
|       4 |       0 |
|       5 |       0 |
|       6 |       0 |
+---------+---------+
```

How might I achieve this?
Thank you

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: 4 and 5 are not even there in table 1's ID2 column. Your question does not make sense.

Comment: @GordonLinoff done

Comment: Where is the definitive list for the resulting table?  Is it all the numbers from 1 to 6?  Or is it all the numbers found in the `id2` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following using a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT id1, IFNULL(cnt, 0) AS IDs FROM table1 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id2, count(*) cnt FROM table1 GROUP BY id2
)x ON table1.id1 = x.id2
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e97c4e/2/0

Answer (score 0):

You need a table of all the values you want in the result set.  Then there are several methods . . . for instance, a correlated subquery:

```
select n.id2,
       (select count(*) from mytable t where t.id2 = n.id2)
from (select 1 as id2 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5
     ) n;
```

Comment: Apologies, forgot to include 6 in the final. I have edited the desired output in the question

Answer (score 0):

You should be trying to figure out how many Id2s match Id1 and you can do this with a left join of the table to itself.

```
SELECT 
  mt1.Id1, 
  COUNT(mt2.Id2) 
FROM 
  MyTable as mt1 LEFT JOIN MyTable as mt2 ON mt1.Id1 = mt2.Id2
GROUP BY
  mt1.Id1
```

All values for id1 will be included and all of the matches for id2 will be counted.  If there is no match for Id1, the count will be 0.